# IIS 10 Error 500.19 (0x80070021) - Lock Violation

Tags: iis, windows-services, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have an application I am trying to migrate from Server 2012 IIS 8 to Server 2016 IIS 10. When I initially move everything over I am receiving the attached error message.

I have read through several stack exchange posts and it basically says the section needs to be unlocked. I have unlocked the section via the command prompt command and via the IIS manager.

The section shows unlocked

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please open applicationHost.config in an editor and search for "lock". The error page says something else, not what you showed in Configuration Editor.

Comment: @LexLi There are several places in the applicationHost.config that contain the word lock for instance. modules -> BasicAuthenticationModuel lockItem = true. Anyway to narrow it down?

Comment: You already narrowed it down to the right level. The actual config item you hit was https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/v12.0.94.0/Tests/original2.config#L1010 where `WindowsAuthenticationModule` is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens only with Modules which are listed as Native. 
To resolve this error you need to unlock this module from the server level.

- Open PowerShell as administrator and run this command.

`Remove-WebConfigurationLock -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/modules/add[@name='WindowsAuthenticationModule']"`

- After unlocking this restart the iis server and try to access the site again.

You can directly unlock this setting using iis manager GUI option.

- Select server name from the iis server node and then select module from feature view.
  [image]
  in modules feature, select which module you want to unlock and then right-click on it and select unlock.
  [image]

and then restart iis server.

Comment: When I ran the powershell script in IIS 10 on Windows 10-1909, the module is named `WindowsAuthentication`, not `WinowsAuthenticationModule` and it is unlocked.  I never had to unlock it.